# Can't boot in to arch linux - '/sbin/init: Bad Exec Format' followed by kernel panic

Tags: linux, kernel, arch-linux

I dual boot Windows 7 & Arch Linux. Arch was stable for a while, but then it stopped booting into Arch, saying '/sbin/init: bad exec format'. This is followed by a kernel panic.

I'm not really sure how to fix this. Can I copy the binary off the USB stick I have that I installed Arch from? Or is it compiled when the kernel updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like your `/sbin/init` has become corrupted. Provided the usb version of Arch you have is the same architecture, then you should be able to copy `init` from the usb to the main installation.

Of course it might be that more than `init` has broken, as it is one of the first executables run after the kernel loads, so you may have more cleaning to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a fallback-image that got made when you updated your kernel or init ramdisk.
Try it by selecting it from the GRUB menu (press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot if GRUB doesn't show up)

An alternative is using your USB stick to rescue the kernel. [Here is a good howto](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=18066) (use USB-stick where it says cd) from the Archlinux forums.